# How to scrape multiple product price from Lazada by just repeat same coding in single Python script to make it as price extractor in single click?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, data-analysis, price

I am trying make a price extractor for 2 or more items by using Python in single script. However, it just work if only one item but when I repeat the code in the script to extract another item price it failed.

In this scenario, it works.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class ScrapeLazada():
    
    def scrape(self):
        url = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/products/polident-whitening-daily-cleanser-36s-i3495374911-s19234844911.html?channelLpJumpArgs=&clickTrackInfo=query%253APOLIDENT%252BWHITENING%252BDAILY%252BCLEANSER%252BFOR%252BDENTURES%252B36%25252527S%253Bnid%253A3495374911%253Bsrc%253ALazadaMainSrp%253Brn%253A968570599022924302566e5f71f239f9%253Bregion%253Amy%253Bsku%253A3495374911_MY%253Bprice%253A18.91%253Bclient%253Adesktop%253Bsupplier_id%253A39196%253Bpromotion_biz%253A%253Basc_category_id%253A10002240%253Bitem_id%253A3495374911%253Bsku_id%253A19234844911%253Bshop_id%253A6771&fastshipping=0&freeshipping=1&fs_ab=2&fuse_fs=1&lang=en&location=Selangor&price=18.91&priceCompare=&ratingscore=0&request_id=968570599022924302566e5f71f239f9&review=&sale=0&search=1&source=search&spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.i15.63181341IcwAkm&stock=1'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        
        products=[]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        for item in soup.findAll('div', class_='pdp-mod-product-price'):
            price = item.find('span', class_='pdp-price pdp-price_type_normal pdp-price_color_orange pdp-price_size_xl').text.replace('RM', '')                               
            products.append(
                (price) 
            )

        df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns=['Price'])
        print(df)
        
        driver.close()
        
sl = ScrapeLazada()
sl.scrape()
```

The outcome above is:

```
     Price
0    18.90
```

however, below script is not working

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class ScrapeLazada():
    
    def scrape(self):
        url = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/products/polident-whitening-daily-cleanser-36s-i3495374911-s19234844911.html?channelLpJumpArgs=&clickTrackInfo=query%253APOLIDENT%252BWHITENING%252BDAILY%252BCLEANSER%252BFOR%252BDENTURES%252B36%25252527S%253Bnid%253A3495374911%253Bsrc%253ALazadaMainSrp%253Brn%253A968570599022924302566e5f71f239f9%253Bregion%253Amy%253Bsku%253A3495374911_MY%253Bprice%253A18.91%253Bclient%253Adesktop%253Bsupplier_id%253A39196%253Bpromotion_biz%253A%253Basc_category_id%253A10002240%253Bitem_id%253A3495374911%253Bsku_id%253A19234844911%253Bshop_id%253A6771&fastshipping=0&freeshipping=1&fs_ab=2&fuse_fs=1&lang=en&location=Selangor&price=18.91&priceCompare=&ratingscore=0&request_id=968570599022924302566e5f71f239f9&review=&sale=0&search=1&source=search&spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.i15.63181341IcwAkm&stock=1'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        
        products=[]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        for item in soup.findAll('div', class_='pdp-mod-product-price'):
            price = item.find('span', class_='pdp-price pdp-price_type_normal pdp-price_color_orange pdp-price_size_xl').text.replace('RM', '')                               
            products.append(
                (price) 
            )

        df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns=['Price'])
        print(df)
        
class ScrapeLazada():
    
    def scrape(self):
        url = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/products/polident-denture-adhesive-cream-flavour-free-60g-i2337287394-s10003213026.html?channelLpJumpArgs=&clickTrackInfo=query%253APOLIDENT%252BDENTURE%252BADHESIVE%252BCREAM%252B60G%252B%252528FLAVOUR%252BFREE%252529%253Bnid%253A2337287394%253Bsrc%253ALazadaMainSrp%253Brn%253Ab84f3568e83a002035527d9e436ba9af%253Bregion%253Amy%253Bsku%253A2337287394_MY%253Bprice%253A21.9%253Bclient%253Adesktop%253Bsupplier_id%253A100040836%253Bpromotion_biz%253A%253Basc_category_id%253A1713%253Bitem_id%253A2337287394%253Bsku_id%253A10003213026%253Bshop_id%253A78741&fastshipping=0&freeshipping=1&fs_ab=2&fuse_fs=1&lang=en&location=Selangor&price=21.9&priceCompare=&ratingscore=4.9298245614035086&request_id=b84f3568e83a002035527d9e436ba9af&review=57&sale=297&search=1&source=search&spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.i40.7c047855gRKu7A&stock=1'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        
        products=[]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        for item in soup.findAll('div', class_='pdp-mod-product-price'):
            price = item.find('span', class_='pdp-price pdp-price_type_normal pdp-price_color_orange pdp-price_size_xl').text.replace('RM', '')                               
            products.append(
                (price) 
            )

        df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns=['Price'])
        print(df)


        driver.close()
        
sl = ScrapeLazada()
sl.scrape()
```

The outcome for the failed script is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b8bf94a96cce> in <module>
     47 
     48 sl = ScrapeLazada()
---> 49 sl.scrape()

<ipython-input-14-b8bf94a96cce> in scrape(self)
     35         soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
     36         for item in soup.findAll('div', class_='pdp-mod-product-price'):
---> 37             price = item.find('span', class_='pdp-price pdp-price_type_normal pdp-price_color_orange pdp-price_size_xl').text.replace('RM', '')
     38             products.append(
     39                 (price)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: Why is the class defined twice in your second script? Or is this meant by *but when I repeat the code in the script to extract another item*

Comment: Just a note in addition and not the issue: *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

Comment: I am new to programming and I think I made a mistake on structuring the code but I couldn't find where is the mistake over there. When I run first script it works well and the outcome is what I expected. So I thought if I repeat the coding again just as I make the second script, I can have the outcome like 2 products price displayed but turns out got the attribute error.

Comment: btw thank you for pointing out my other issues